# Serialize from/to null

Tags: json, rust, serde

I figured out how to serialize a unit-like enum variant to `null` in JSON, but is there a simple way of de-serializing it from `null` without having to write a dedicated deserialization function?

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde_json::from_str;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Entry(String, String);

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Action {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "serde::ser::Serializer::serialize_none")]
    Delete(),
    Create(Entry),
}
type Actions = Vec<Action>;

#[test]
fn this_works() {
  from_str::<Actions>(r#"[["id", "value"], []]"#).unwrap();
}

#[test]
fn this_does_not_work() {
  // ... but this is what I would like to use
  from_str::<Actions>(r#"[["id", "value"], null]"#).unwrap();
}
```

See [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use+serde%3A%3A%7BSerialize%2C+Deserialize%7D%3B%0Ause+serde_json%3A%3Afrom_str%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive%28Serialize%2C+Deserialize%29%5D%0Astruct+Entry%28String%2C+String%29%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive%28Serialize%2C+Deserialize%29%5D%0A%23%5Bserde%28untagged%29%5D%0Aenum+Action+%7B%0A++++%23%5Bserde%28serialize_with+%3D+%22serde%3A%3Aser%3A%3ASerializer%3A%3Aserialize_none%22%29%5D%0A++++Delete%28%29%2C%0A++++Create%28Entry%29%2C%0A%7D%0Atype+Actions+%3D+Vec%3CAction%3E%3B%0A%0A%23%5Btest%5D%0Afn+this_works%28%29+%7B%0A++from_str%3A%3A%3CActions%3E%28r%23%22%5B%5B%22id%22%2C+%22value%22%5D%2C+%5B%5D%5D%22%23%29.unwrap%28%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Btest%5D%0Afn+this_does_not_work%28%29+%7B%0A++%2F%2F+...+but+this+is+what+I+would+like+to+use%0A++from_str%3A%3A%3CActions%3E%28r%23%22%5B%5B%22id%22%2C+%22value%22%5D%2C+null%5D%22%23%29.unwrap%28%29%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: You can make `Delete` (without parentheses!) the `#[default]` and `#[derive(Default)]` but that means your currently working solution doesn't work any more.

Comment: @cafce25 That's precisely what I was looking for. Can you make it an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @cafce25, this works as expected:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde_json::from_str;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Entry(String, String);

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Default)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Action {
    #[default]
    Delete,
    Create(Entry),
}
type Actions = Vec<Action>;

#[test]
fn works() {
  from_str::<Actions>(r#"[["id", "value"], null]"#).unwrap();
}
```

Try on [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=use+serde%3A%3A%7BSerialize%2C+Deserialize%7D%3B%0Ause+serde_json%3A%3Afrom_str%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive%28Serialize%2C+Deserialize%29%5D%0Astruct+Entry%28String%2C+String%29%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive%28Serialize%2C+Deserialize%2C+Default%29%5D%0A%23%5Bserde%28untagged%29%5D%0Aenum+Action+%7B%0A++++%23%5Bdefault%5D%0A++++Delete%2C%0A++++Create%28Entry%29%2C%0A%7D%0Atype+Actions+%3D+Vec%3CAction%3E%3B%0A%0A%23%5Btest%5D%0Afn+this_is_what_i_want%28%29+%7B%0A++from_str%3A%3A%3CActions%3E%28r%23%22%5B%5B%22id%22%2C+%22value%22%5D%2C+null%5D%22%23%29.unwrap%28%29%3B%0A%7D).